receiving system.io.ioexception when i try to connect postgresql db (using IIS)
version info.
gpdb (postgresql): 6.X
npgsql : 4.0.10
.net framework : 4.8
IIS
The issue is that when I open only one port on IIS and run the app, it works fine.
But when I open two ports, I keep getting the error Npgsql.NpgsqlException(0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream --> System.IO.IOException: The transmission connection was closed or a response was not received from the connected member.
Originally, I was using npgsql version 3.0.5 without any issues. However, when I tried to connect to a different Greenplum DB (based on PostgreSQL) with the same version, I encountered a connection error, so I upgraded to version 4.0.10.
Even though I want to use the latest npgsql version, connection errors occur, so I'm currently testing with version 4.0.10. The Greenplum DB version is 6, maybe 6.25.4, but I'm not sure.
when I open two ports, The error occurs repeatedly causing the connection to keep dropping. Sometimes it manages to reconnect successfully after several attempts, but sometimes it keeps failing. Interestingly, there is no issue when only one port is open
I want to know why this is happening.

when I open two ports. Will this happen to any two ports? Have you tried other port? Try using cmd netstat –aon | findstr <port number> or TCPView to check the port occupancy. Then check the IIS log for more information.

yes i tried other ports. When using a different GPDB, all ports functioned normally. However, after changing only the database information, this issue occurred. Could this be caused by the database being installed in a different region? We're using approximately 140TB of storage.

Check the PostgreSQL Log, it helps you gain insight into your database activity.
